# What do i need to resign ipa files?

Tags: ios, ipa, provisioning, signing

I was hoping that someone could explain to me the process about resigning existing IPA files and install it OTA. I'm unsure what certificates I need to have and how to sign it properly so it can be used by my own device.

I do have the following:

- existing IPA file (developed by someone else)
- Apple developer account
- my udid registered in my developer portal
- manifest.plist, ipa file, index.html referring to the files

I’ve seen several posts about this but none really worked out for me. However, I do get the message that I can install the ipa but it turns out to be grey once finished paired with the error:

> cannot install ipa try again